# Dynamic Chart Range - a formula in this worksheet contains one or more invalid references- VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts, range

I am using named ranges to create charts dynamically. I take a snapshot every 5 minutes of data and add a new line. The charts update correctly when new data is added.

However, when I clear the first line of data then I get error messages saying

> a formula in this worksheet contains one or more invalid references.

I can't do anything because the pop up won't stop coming up. Is there a way to make my formula stronger so it accounts for when the first row is cleared?

My formula:

```
=OFFSET(Spreads!$B$130,1,0,COUNTA(Spreads!$B$131:$B$1048576),1)
```

The header starts in cell B130, but the first line of data is in B131. I tried using the Indirect formula, but that didn't seem to help. I am not deleting rows either, I am just clearing the data.

Comment: Does your formula end up looking like this:  `=OFFSET(Spreads!#REF!,1,0,COUNTA(Spreads!$B$130:$B$1048576),1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `INDEX`:

`=INDEX($B:$B,131):INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($B$130:$B$1048576)+130)`

This returns a reference to the 131st row in column B extended to the 130th+COUNT row in column B.
It's also non-volatile unlike `OFFSET` - They are only recalculated when any of the function's arguments change.

Comment: That fixed it! Awesome, thanks so much for the help!